# Hanging at "Running Transaction Test" when trying to install php-soap

Tags: centos, mount, software-installation, yum, upgrade

I have here a CentOS 5 and I'm trying to run `yum install php-soap` but the installer hangs on and the last step is `Running Transaction Test`.

I found out that NFS shares are the problem. See [here](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2008-01/msg02242.html) or [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=243420) or [here](http://www.unix.com/linux/161711-yum-hangs-running-transaction-test.html). I tried to unmount everything which came up when entering `cat /etc/mtab | grep nfs`. I also tried to use `umount -a -t nfs`. Then I run the install command. But I can't get this working.

`strace yum -y update` show me many lines, but I can't get a sense out of it.

Furthermore I tried

```
/bin/rm /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
cd /var/cache/yum
/bin/rm -rf *
yum clean all
yum update
```

but still hangs on.

Do I have to remove the mounts from the other server to this machine?

Comment: NFS mounts themselves are not necessarily the problem.  _Stale_ NFS mounts can be a problem, as mentioned in the links you provided.  If `df` doesn't hang, and doesn't mention stale NFS mounts, then that is not likely the cause of your problem.  Can you provide the last 10-20 or so lines of the `strace` output?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this steps :
1. Kill all RPM and yum processes (rhn_check, yum, rpm, rhn-applet):

> ps -axwww | grep rpm

n the list of processes, the first number on each line is the PID. For all PIDs listed except for the one associated with grep:

> kill -9

Repeat the above steps for each of the programs listed.

2. Remove any RPM lock files (/var/lib/rpm/__db*):

> rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db*

3. Rebuild the RPM database:

> rpm --rebuilddb

Have Nice time.